# How to increase the priority of custom overloaded function signatures?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'll give you an example, actually it's just an example, the discussion point is not the example itself.

I wrote a setTimeout function and found several signatures, and they have an order.

- @types/node/timers.d.ts
- typescript/lib

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtE4a.png)

I was not satisfied with the signature they provided, so I decided to customize the signature of the "reset" function.
I know to use window.setTimeout, but the point is not to discuss that. Because there are many other functions that also have this situation.

```
// src/typings/reset.d.ts

declare function setTimeout(callback?: () => void, ms?: number): number
```

This is good, he works, the type signature of the function is already loaded, and they have an order.

@types/node/timers.d.ts
typescript/lib
src/typings/reset.d.ts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXPLl.png)

But when I start to actually write code, this time the return value will be determined because the imported parameters match, and everything changes.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJIAE.png)

This is not what I expected. What about the custom function signatures in reset.d.ts that I expected?

And how to control the signature order of typescript loading? make

- @types/node/timers.d.ts
- typescript/lib
- src/typings/reset.d.ts

to

- src/typings/reset.d.ts
- @types/node/timers.d.ts
- typescript/lib

increase the priority of custom overloaded function signatures

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Screenshots of IDEs are unfortunately not appropriate here. [Please replace images of code/logs/errors/tooltips with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218). Right now it risks being closed as lacking debugging details.